# Evaluating complex lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda expression that I want to shorten by combining two function calls inside. If you see in below code I am calling `this.adgroupRepository.GetBidRange` twice. There has to be a way to combine these calls into one and just pass the FloorValue and CeilingValue from within.

Can someone help?

```
new JsonResult
{
    Data = result.Data.Where(x => x.Bidding != null).Select(
        x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.Name,
            BidRange = new
            {
                FloorValue = (x.Bidding.FloorPrice != null) ? x.Bidding.FloorPrice : this.adgroupRepository.GetBidRange(this.contextProvider.CurrentAccount.CurrencyCode, x.PricingModel, x.Bidding.Type).FloorValue,
                CeilingValue = (x.Bidding.CeilingPrice != null) ? x.Bidding.CeilingPrice : this.adgroupRepository.GetBidRange(this.contextProvider.CurrentAccount.CurrencyCode, x.PricingModel, x.Bidding.Type).CeilingValue
            },
            DefaultBid = x.Bidding.BroadBid
        })
};
```

Comment: A method can return only one object.  If the method GetBidRange() returns only a single number then the code cannot be changed.  If you modify GetBidRange() to return a different object like a KeyPairValue which can return two numbers then the code can be simplifier.

Comment: @jdweng It already returns an object with `FloorValue` and `CeilingValue` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use a lambda statement instead of an expression.  That allows you to write a block of code, create local variables, and then return the result.  Also you can use the null-coalescing operator `??` instead of the conditional operator with a `null` check.

```
new JsonResult
{
    Data = result.Data.Where(x => x.Bidding != null).Select(
        x => 
        {                
            var bidRange = 
                x.Bidding.FloorPrice == null
                    || x.Bidding.CeilingPrice == null ?
                this.adgroupRepository.GetBidRange(
                    this.contextProvider.CurrentAccount.CurrencyCode, 
                    x.PricingModel, 
                    x.Bidding.Type) :
                null; 
            return new
            {
                x.ID,
                x.Name,
                BidRange = new
                {
                    FloorValue = x.Bidding.FloorPrice ?? bidRange.FloorValue,
                    CeilingValue = x.Bidding.CeilingPrice ?? bidRange.CeilingValue
                },
                DefaultBid = x.Bidding.BroadBid
            };
        })
};
```

Comment: A minor drawback of this solution is that `GetBidRange` is always called, even if both `x.Bidding.FloorPrice` and `x.Bidding.CeilingPrice` are non-null.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer guys. Is there a way to optimize this more? i.e. not to call GetBidRange when the non-null values are already present?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Sure, you can just put a condition that you only call it when at least one of them is null.  I've updated my answer using the conditional operator for that, but you can also use a traditional `if` statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 new JsonResult
 {
       Data = result.Data.Where(x => x.Bidding != null).Select(x => 
       {
           var bidRange = adgroupRepository.GetBidRange(
                contextProvider.CurrentAccount.CurrencyCode, 
                x.PricingModel, 
                x.Bidding.Type);
           return new
           {
               ID = x.ID,
               Name = x.Name,
               BidRange = new
               {
                   FloorValue = x.Bidding.FloorPrice ?? bidRange.FloorValue,
                   CeilingValue = x.Bidding.CeilingPrice ?? bidRange .CeilingValue
               },
               DefaultBid = x.Bidding.BroadBid
           }
       })
 };
```

Comment: You have to `return` the anonymous type for this to compile.

Comment: @juharr Thanks. I wrote the answer from my phone.. Ill update it.